# Find zero divisors for polynomials in several variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I don't know how to find ***all*** zero divisors for polynomials in several variables. For example:

### $\mathbb{Z}_2[X,Y]/(X^2,XY,Y^2)\quad $ or  $\quad \mathbb{Z}_4[X,Y]/(X^2,Y^2-XY)$

Can we  to proceed like in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ over a non irreducible polynomial by using euclidian divison, and find all zero divisors for this ring?

Comment: What is $(X+Y)(X+Y)$?

Comment: $=0$ but I want a method or a procedure that I must use to find all of the zero divisor

Comment: "But I don't know how to start" - well, this was meant as a start for you.

Comment: I am not a native speaker that why I didn't express my self well. I change it now. My goal is to find all zero divisor not only one

Comment: Both rings are local and artinian, so the maximal ideal is the set of all zero-divisors.

Comment: In general, given an ideal $\mathfrak a$ which admits a primary decomposition, you can find the set of all zero divisors of $R/\mathfrak a$ by computing the union of the primes associated to $\mathfrak a$

Comment: In an elementary way, think about the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[X,Y]/(X^2,XY,Y^2)$ as being of the form $a+bx+cy$ with $a,b,c\in\{0,1\}$. Notice that $bx+cy$ are zero-divisors, and $1+bx+cy$ are invertible.

Comment: Similarly, the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_4[X,Y]/(X^2,Y^2-XY)$ are of the form $a+bx+cy+dxy$, and those with $a=0$ are zero-divisors.